# "Do nothing" in the else-part of the ternary operator?

Tags: c++, ternary-operator

What's the standard line to add to the ternary operator in order to do nothing if the condition is not met?

Example:

```
int a = 0;
a > 10 ? a = 5 : /*do nothing*/;
```

Using `a` seems to do the trick, but I am wondering if there is a more generally accepted way.

Comment: I would just use an if () instead in this case since it improves readability.

Comment: Ternary operator with assignment as side effect? No, please don't.

Comment: The generally accepted way is to not use the ternary operator for side effects.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That will do it:

```
a = a > 10 ? 5 : a;
```

or simply:

```
if (a > 10) a = 5;
```

Answer (score 6):

Another option:

```
a ? void(a = 0) : void();
```

What's good about this one is that it works even if you can't construct an instance of `decltype(a = 0)` to put into the 'do nothing' expression. (Which doesn't matter for primitive types anyway.)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use a logical expression (though maybe confusing) in case you don't want to use an if statement.

```
a > 10 && a = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
a > 10 ? a=5 : 0;
```

But, I would prefer:

```
if (a > 10) 
   a = 5;
```

Comment: I wouldn't do that. For example, with strings this code will crush!
std::string s{};
s.empty() ? "some sting" : 0;

Answer (score 0):

Just for a sake of variety, but not recommending as it is very ambiguous.

```
void do_smth()
{}

bool a = true; // not necessarily 

a && (do_smth(), 0);
```